# Can we shift Delaware LLC ownership percentages without exchanging money?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, shares

There are three people in a Delaware LLC, acting as a partnership. We have a formula that we use when we distribute money (based on hours worked, mostly), so our distributions generally don't line up with our ownership percentages.

Two of us would like to change our ownership percentages, and in exchange we'd modify the distribution formula to favor the person losing ownership.

We don't have anything in our operating agreement that either prohibits or specifically allows it, so we're relying on the fact that all three of us are in agreement.

Is there any reason why this wouldn't work? I know for other business types, like an S-Corp, you generally have to be paid outright using Fair Market Value of the shares, but that doesn't seem to be the case for LLCs.

Comment: Is “partnership” the same thing as “ownership” in your context? I see that you’re using the term “distribution” and not “dividend”, so is the “partnership” something that allows you to exercise discretion (legally) in the distributions paid out to different partners?

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, we have the ability to decide the distribution in any way that we'd like.

Comment: What about ownership? Is the percentage split based on shares held or is it more a notional gentleman’s agreement? Typically, ownership percentage is concrete (eg number of shares held), and changing ownership requires some kind of buying and selling of shares. But the way you word your question suggests that you are using a less formal split of ownership percentages. So if everything is discretionary, it’s somewhat unclear what more you’re looking for in the question.

Comment: @Lawrence Ownership is by percentages, not by share (as an LLC, we don't officially have shares). 

That's really the thing, I'm fairly certain everything is discretionary, but I'd heard from someone that it might not be, so I'm trying to understand if my thinking is right, or if there's something I haven't found yet.